How to format a general date to a distinct month in a combobox dropdown list in Access VBA?
I have here a combobox which is getting values from a Date column of a table. So this is how it looks like:

Is there a way that I can convert the date list of the combobox into distinct months like this below?

I looked at this method from its answer but this is using Excel and I am on Access and still new to Access.
Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

You can use the following SQL as your RowSource for the ComboBox (see image below):
SELECT Month([fldDate]) AS MonthNumber, Format([fldDate],"mmmm") AS MonthText
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY Month([fldDate]), Format([fldDate],"mmmm");

Your ComboBox should be defined with two columns. Column widths should be 0cm;2cm which will hide the first column. The Bound Column property should be set to 1 so you can reference the user selection simply by using ComboBox.Value. The user can select by month name but you will use the month number (first column) for any additional processing.
You do not mention whether the table contains data for 1 year only. If you have multiple years then you will need to take that into consideration.


will try. be ryt back

hi.  aplogies. I am quite new. i changed the fldDate to my datefield and YourTableName to my tablename and used this code strSQL = "SELECT Month([fldDate]) AS MonthNumber, Format([fldDate],"mmmm") AS MonthText FROM YourTableName GROUP BY Month([fldDate]), Format([fldDate],"mmmm");" and Dim strSQL As String above it but I am having a red text in the long sql code.

The SQL should be placed into the RowSource property of the ComboBox. You don't need strSQL = or quotes on either side.

okay yes will be right back

worked like a charm!!!

I edited my answer above as well. Note what I wrote about the Bound Column. Cheers.

If your months are rolling, you may consider ordering also by the year to keep the order of the months when spanning New Year:
SELECT Month([fldDate]) AS MonthNumber, Format([fldDate],"mmmm") AS MonthText
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY Year([fldDate]), Month([fldDate]), Format([fldDate],"mmmm")

